# No live audio input: [object NavigatorUserMediaError]

Tags: html

I am trying out the example given here https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs - example_simple_exportwav.html. But, I am getting this error

```
No live audio input: [object NavigatorUserMediaError]
```

I am on WindowsXP and have enabled WebAudio for Chrome (Version 24.0.1312.56 m). What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue, with the same example.  Turns out you have to be serving the page from an HTTP server, as Chrome won't allow the audio input from a "file:///" page.  An easy way to accomplish this, if you have Python installed, is to run the following in the directory containing the example file:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Now, point Chrome localhost:8000 and the example should work.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have to run it in HTTPS not HTTP.

When you are in https, the browser ask you for the permission of the microphone.

Hope you find this helpful.